# Should "bad" questions be instantly downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the front page there are a few questions with -2 to -3 votes. They have all been asked by new users. A recent SE change let us downvote questions without fear of a reputation loss, but should people really be doing this without giving the user a chance to update their question? This site is lacking users, so to instantly downvote a question with -3 votes is not going to encourage a user to stick around. Even if they do clean the question up it will probably still remain in the negatives due to the site's current small senior user base.

So I don't think downvoting a new user's question into oblivion is helpful or good for this site and we should just leave a comment and/or flag. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I partialy agree with @Joe. But I think is better make a comment and if the OP not changes the questions then downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Joe> When I downvote, I always provide a reason

That appears to be a rather idealised view of what I've seen of your actions. What is actually happening is that questions are being deleted by Joe or someone to try and make the site look better.

If people can't get answers and their questions are regualrly downvoted, closed, locked, or deleted then there is a serious problem in the site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are only two questions on the entire site that are negative in their votes at the moment. One was closed as "Too localised", and another about finding a specific phone cover, also closed.

That said, it would be nice if people voted for good questions (and answers) more, or if there were more questions being asked. After all, if you think questions are being unfairly downvoted, you can vote for them...

On the wider subject of voting, it's a bit of a shame that [only 4 people](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/badges/71/vox-populi) have used all their votes in a day...

Comment: I was just looking at the front page and saw those two, I could have sworn that there were more. I agree that the lack of up-voting is a bigger problem than this, but due to the lack of activity I was thinking that this would scare new users off. Looking forward to ~October

Comment: Most of the older heavily downvoted, closed questions had been deleted

Answer (score 0):

When I downvote, I always provide a reason. When/if the user fixes the questions I remove the vote as well. If you don't like that approach, you can always comment, *then* downvote the next day if it isn't fixed.

The solution isn't to stop downvoting, but to tell the user why it is a bad question. **If they fix the problem, remove the downvote**

I know we don't have many users (and even fewer on meta!), but we shouldn't let bad questions run the site. Would that make the internet a better place?

Comment: But does it really help to continue to initially downvote it past -1? It can still be closed if it is bad. If the OP of http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/725/where-can-i-find-a-lumia-710-dark-knight-rises-xpress-on-cover managed to change it to something less localised he would have little chance of coming back from -3, so he would have little motivation to actually try to salvage it. I am just trying to look at it from a new users POV, yes they should have read the FAQ, but most people don't and a quick -3 isn't very welcoming.